# Making a network call to update UI from within an observer method in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm building an app where a user can add their calendar availabilities, and delete these availabilities. I set up an observer method in the onViewCreated of my Fragment that's called everytime a user clicks on my calendar date. Through my current implementation, the code works as expected the first time and then I run into some weird bugs (API call doesn't go through / UI doesn't update as expected) in subsequent calls. My code is below:

```
        init {

            view.setOnClickListener {

                dateTimeViewModel.haveOwnTimeslotsBeenUpdated.observe(
                viewLifecycleOwner,
                Observer { isOwnTimeslotUpdated ->

                    if (isOwnTimeslotUpdated) {

                        val startOfTimeframe =
                            LocalDate.now().yearMonth.minusMonths(10).atDay(1)
                                .atStartOfDay(timezone).toEpochSecond()

                        val endOfTimeframe =
                            LocalDate.now().yearMonth.plusMonths(10).atDay(1)
                                .atStartOfDay(
                                    timezone
                                ).toEpochSecond()


                        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
                            val response = dateTimeViewModel.getOwnTimeslots(
                                    startOfTimeframe,
                                    endOfTimeframe
                                )
                            val listOfTimeslots = handleResponse(response)

                            mapOfDatesAndTimeslots =
                                storeLocalDateAndTimeslotsInAMap(listOfTimeslots)

                            val dates = mapOfDatesAndTimeslots.keys

                            if(selectedDate in dates){
                                val listOfTimeslotsOnADate = mapOfDatesAndTimeslots[selectedDate]

                                val areTimeslotsWorthDisplaying = listOfTimeslotsOnADate!!.any{ timeslot ->
                                    timeslot.timeslot_status == 0 || timeslot.timeslot_status == 1 || timeslot.timeslot_status == 2
                                }

                                if(areTimeslotsWorthDisplaying){
                                    calendarDayDotView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                    sortTimeslotsOnAParticularDate(listOfTimeslotsOnADate)
                                } else {
                                    calendarDayDotView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                                    clearRecyclerViews()
                                }
                            } else {
                                calendarDayDotView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                                clearRecyclerViews()
                            }
                        }
                        dateTimeViewModel.setHaveOwnTimeslotsBeenUpdatedToFalse()
                    }
                }
            )

        }
    }
```

After the first call, my UI to display the dot doesn't work as expected, and neither does my sorting of timeslots despite working fine the first time. I have a feeling it's because this line of code is called repeatedly : `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted` but I could be wrong. I'm not sure if it's best practice to make an API call from within an observer method and then reset the observed variable to false, so please share your suggestions if any. Please help me, and thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

What does your view model look like ?

A red flag would be setting the observers within your click listener but I'm not sure of you're thinking about it hence more code would be nice to review